# Filtering pivot table data using intermediate relationship in Laravel eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm working on Access Control Level (ACL) in laravel. here is, two `pivot` table one is `role_user` which is represent the `each users roles` and another one is `permission_role` which is represent the `each roles permissions`. now I want to get the `permission_role` pivot table data from `User`model.

my code samples.

```
In User Model

public function roles()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class);
}

In Role Model

public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
}

public function permissions()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Permission::class);
}
In Permission Model

public function roles()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class);
}
```

**I'm try this way:-**

```
$user->roles->with('permissions')->get();
```

> it shows BadMethodException.

How could i solve this issue and get the desire output.

Comment: shouldn't it be `$user->roles()->...`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to eager load nested relationships you can do by using the dot separated syntax e.g.:

```
User::with('roles.permissions')->find($id);
```

If the `User` model has already been instantiated then you can use the `load()` method instead (lazy eager loading):

```
$user->load('roles.permissions');
```

[Eager Loading Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads)

Comment: **$this->roles()->with('permissions')->get();** i'm use this query but i want to use `where` clause this query to fetch the specific permission id. How can i do this ??

Comment: @Gabrielle What does `$this` refer to? Also, are you only wanting to get roles that have a certain permission?

Comment: `$this` means current logged in user, i'm wanting the all `permissions`, that logged user `roles` have.

Comment: @Gabrielle Something like this should do the trick: `return Permission::whereHas('roles', function ($query) {
    $query->whereHas('user', function ($query) {
        $query->where('id', $this->id);
    });
})->get();`